# Installing Ruby on Linode Server

Tags: ruby, linode

This linode [guide](http://library.linode.com/frameworks/sinatra/debian-6-squeeze) provides instructions on how to install ruby on the server. The guide uses ruby 1.8 which is installed alongside other dependencies. How can I alter these commands to setup ruby 1.9.2? The dependencies seem to be linked to each other.

Linode guide's commands:

Install Ruby dependencies

`apt-get install wget build-essential ruby1.8 ruby1.8-dev irb1.8 rdoc1.8 zlib1g-dev libopenssl-ruby1.8 rubygems1.8 libopenssl-ruby libzlib-ruby libssl-dev libpcre3-dev  libcurl4-openssl-dev`

Create symbolic links

`ln -s /usr/bin/ruby1.8 /usr/bin/ruby`

`ln -s /usr/bin/irb1.8 /usr/bin/irb`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[RVM](https://rvm.io/rvm/install/) is a very popular tool for installing Ruby.

Comment: Thanks @Zeke I use RVM locally, but I've heard horror stories of using it on the server. I don't remember exactly what those people were experiencing. Are there any precautions that I should take when installing it on the server? e.g. "Install system-wide, do not switch versions.."?

Comment: @Dru There have been quite a few stability improvements recently. I use a multi-user and project-specific gemsets. Make sure you add deploy users to the rvm group and follow the documentation's directions/warning regarding root/sudo. I haven't had had issues upgrading to a new stable version of rvm in quite a while.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give RVM a try server-side

Comment: My answer was used to install on a server (deb6@linode) as root btw. I had the same apprehensions but its turned out ok.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to install ruby 1.9.2 or 1.9.3 I'd recommend using rbenv (http://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv)

For installing on a ubuntu machine the following should work:

```
curl -L https://raw.github.com/fesplugas/rbenv-installer/master/bin/rbenv-installer | bash
vim ~/.bashrc # add rbenv to the top
. ~/.bashrc
rbenv bootstrap-ubuntu-10-04
rbenv install 1.9.(your preffered version here)
rbenv global 1.9.(your preffered version here)
```

Answer (score -1):

I did this just a week or so ago, here's my play-by-play log

```
# download rvm script
curl -L get.rvm.io > install-rvm
chmod +x install-rvm
sudo ./install-rvm

# add our user into rvm group
usermod -a -G rvm `whoami`
# log out & in
logout

# IMPORTANT: install dependencies given from command below
rvm requirements 
apt-get $deps-from-rvm
rvm install 1.9.3 #possibly do this with rvmsudo to install it globally
```

I know it doesn't directly help your current situation, but using RVM is really recommended in the ruby world. I would back out of your apt-get method and use RVM. The apt-get packages are surely out of date anyway.